# PyQt5 Как передать значение из дочернего окна в главное

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer

Программа состоит с двух файлов питона и двух файлов со стилями окон.

Помогите передать значение с текстового поля `lineedit` дочернего окна в главное окно в поле `label`.

Главное окно имеет такой код (**main.py**):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
import zavd_form

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("main.ui", self)
        self.zavdannia_button.clicked.connect(self.open_zavdannia)

        self.label_kof_2.setText(str(float()))
        self.label_san_2.setText(str(float()))
        self.label_vid_2.setText(str(float()))
        self.label_lisove_gospodarstvo.setText(str())
        self.window2 = zavd_form.zavd_window()

    def open_zavdannia(self):
    self.window2.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Второй файл (**zavd_for.py**)

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
import main


class zavd_window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("zavd.ui", self)
    
self.zavdannia_vidpravka_button.clicked.connect(self.vidpravlennia_znachen)

    def vidpravlennia_znachen(self):
        #тут я хз как передать значения с дочернего окна в главное
self.zavdannia = main.MainWindow(self.zavd_lisgosp.text(), self.zavd_kof.text(), self.zavd_sanitarni.text(), self.zavd_vidvedennia.text())
```

Файл стилей (**main.ui**)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>655</width>
    <height>455</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_kof">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>30</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>250</width>
      <height>40</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Ваш коефіцієнт </string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_san">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>30</x>
      <y>50</y>
      <width>261</width>
      <height>40</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Вибіркові санітарні рубки</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_vid">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>30</x>
      <y>100</y>
      <width>251</width>
      <height>51</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>10</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="acceptDrops">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Відведення лісосік під рубання, пов’язані з веденням лісового господарства</string>
    </property>
    <property name="scaledContents">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="wordWrap">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="openExternalLinks">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_kof_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>360</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>71</width>
      <height>40</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
      <underline>true</underline>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>_____</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_san_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>360</x>
      <y>50</y>
      <width>71</width>
      <height>40</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
      <underline>true</underline>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>_____</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_vid_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>360</x>
      <y>110</y>
      <width>71</width>
      <height>40</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
      <underline>true</underline>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>_____</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="zavdannia_button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>510</x>
      <y>370</y>
      <width>111</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Завдання</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="tabl_21_button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>30</x>
      <y>220</y>
      <width>111</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Таблиця 2.1</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="tabl_22_button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>190</x>
      <y>220</y>
      <width>111</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Таблиця 2.2</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="tabl_31_button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>350</x>
      <y>220</y>
      <width>111</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Таблиця 3.1</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="tabl_32_button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>510</x>
      <y>220</y>
      <width>111</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Таблиця 3.2</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="tabl_36_button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>510</x>
      <y>270</y>
      <width>111</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Таблиця 3.6</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="tabl_35_button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>350</x>
      <y>270</y>
      <width>111</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Таблиця 3.5</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="tabl_33_button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>30</x>
      <y>270</y>
      <width>111</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Таблиця 3.3</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="tabl_34_button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>190</x>
      <y>270</y>
      <width>111</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Таблиця 3.4</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="tabl_43_button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>350</x>
      <y>320</y>
      <width>111</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Таблиця 4.3</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="tabl_41_button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>30</x>
      <y>320</y>
      <width>111</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Таблиця 4.1</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="tabl_51_button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>510</x>
      <y>320</y>
      <width>111</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Таблиця 5.1</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="tabl_42_button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>190</x>
      <y>320</y>
      <width>111</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Таблиця 4.2</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="tabl_62_button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>350</x>
      <y>370</y>
      <width>111</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Таблиця 6.2</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="tabl_52_button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>30</x>
      <y>370</y>
      <width>111</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Таблиця 5.2</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="tabl_61_button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>190</x>
      <y>370</y>
      <width>111</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Таблиця 6.1</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="send_excel_button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>440</x>
      <y>30</y>
      <width>181</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Відправити в EXCEL</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="DP">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>90</x>
      <y>160</y>
      <width>41</width>
      <height>31</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>ДП &quot;</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_lisove_gospodarstvo">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>130</x>
      <y>170</y>
      <width>211</width>
      <height>21</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>____________________</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="lisove_gospodarstvo">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>350</x>
      <y>170</y>
      <width>211</width>
      <height>21</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>лісове господарство&quot;</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>655</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я отметил вам строки, которые надо изменить, удалить и добавить.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic
#from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
#import zavd_form
from zavd_form import zavd_window


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        uic.loadUi("main.ui", self)

        self.zavdannia_button.clicked.connect(self.open_zavdannia)

#        self.label_kof_2.setText(str(float()))
#        self.label_san_2.setText(str(float()))
#        self.label_vid_2.setText(str(float()))
#        self.label_lisove_gospodarstvo.setText(str())

#        self.window2 = zavd_form.zavd_window(self)                   
        self.window2 = zavd_window(self)                               # + self

    def open_zavdannia(self):
        self.window2.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**zavd_form.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic
#from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
#import main


class zavd_window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
#        super().__init__()
        super(zavd_window, self).__init__(parent)                  # +++

        self.parent = parent                                       # +++

        uic.loadUi("zavd.ui", self)

        self.zavdannia_vidpravka_button.clicked.connect(self.vidpravlennia_znachen)

    def vidpravlennia_znachen(self):
        print("#тут я хз как передать значения с дочернего окна в главное")
#        self.zavdannia = main.MainWindow(self.zavd_lisgosp.text(), self.zavd_kof.text(), self.zavd_sanitarni.text(), self.zavd_vidvedennia.text())

        self.parent.label_kof_2.setText(str(float(self.zavd_kof.text())))          # +++
        self.parent.label_san_2.setText(str(float(self.zavd_sanitarni.text())))    # +++
        self.parent.label_vid_2.setText(str(float(self.zavd_vidvedennia.text())))  # +++
        self.parent.label_lisove_gospodarstvo.setText(self.zavd_lisgosp.text())    # +++
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Второй файл стилей (zavd.ui)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>zavdannia</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="zavdannia">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>688</width>
    <height>816</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QWidget" name="gridLayoutWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>50</y>
      <width>653</width>
      <height>678</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
      <weight>50</weight>
      <bold>false</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <layout class="QGridLayout" name="grid">
     <item row="12" column="0" colspan="2">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_12">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>3.1 Штучне лісовідновлення</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="14" column="0" colspan="3">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_14">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>4. Охорона лісу від пожеж</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="11" column="0" colspan="3">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_11">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>3. Лісокультурні роботи в держлісфонді</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="13" column="0" colspan="2">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_13">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>3.2 Сприяння природному поновленню</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="16" column="0" colspan="3">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_16">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>5. Боротьба зі шкідниками та хворобами лісу</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="15" column="0" colspan="2">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_15">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>4.1 Влаштування мінералізованих смуг</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="17" column="0" colspan="2">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_17">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>5.1 Лісопатологічні обстеження</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="18" column="0" colspan="2">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_18">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>5.2 Грунтові розкопки</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="2">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_20">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>лісове господарство&quot;</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="1" column="0" colspan="2">
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="zavd_kof">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="0">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_19">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>ДП &quot;</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="2" column="0" colspan="3">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>1. Рубання пов’язані з веденням лісового господарства</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="4" column="0" colspan="2">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>- освітлення і прочищення</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="5" column="0" colspan="2">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_5">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>- проріджування</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="3" column="0" colspan="2">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>1.1 Рубання по догляду за лісом, всього</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="6" column="0" colspan="2">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_6">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>- прохідні рубання</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="8" column="0" colspan="3">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_8">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>2. Допоміжні лісогосподарські роботи</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="9" column="0" colspan="2">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_9">
       <property name="enabled">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
         <horstretch>100</horstretch>
         <verstretch>100</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>0</width>
         <height>40</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="maximumSize">
        <size>
         <width>16777215</width>
         <height>40</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="baseSize">
        <size>
         <width>0</width>
         <height>0</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true"/>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>2.1 Відведення лісосік під рубання, пов’язані з веденням лісового господасртва</string>
       </property>
       <property name="wordWrap">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="7" column="0" colspan="2">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_7">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>1.2 Санітарні рубання вибіркові</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="10" column="0" colspan="2">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_10">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>2.2 Трелювання деревини на верхній склад</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="9" column="2">
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="zavd_vidvedennia">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="baseSize">
        <size>
         <width>100</width>
         <height>40</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
         <weight>50</weight>
         <bold>false</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="1">
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="zavd_lisgosp">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
         <weight>50</weight>
         <bold>false</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="1" column="2">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Ваш коефіцієнт</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="7" column="2">
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="zavd_sanitarni">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="baseSize">
        <size>
         <width>100</width>
         <height>40</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
         <weight>50</weight>
         <bold>false</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="3" column="2">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_vsogo">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
         <weight>50</weight>
         <bold>false</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>13.700</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="4" column="2">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_osv">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
         <weight>50</weight>
         <bold>false</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>1.200</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="5" column="2">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_prg">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
         <weight>50</weight>
         <bold>false</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>3.500</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="6" column="2">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_prh">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
         <weight>50</weight>
         <bold>false</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>9.000</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="10" column="2">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_treluv">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
         <weight>50</weight>
         <bold>false</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="12" column="2">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_sht_vid">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
         <weight>50</weight>
         <bold>false</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>100</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="13" column="2">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_ponov">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
         <weight>50</weight>
         <bold>false</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>50</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="15" column="2">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_minsmugi">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
         <weight>50</weight>
         <bold>false</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>200</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="17" column="2">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_obsteg">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
         <weight>50</weight>
         <bold>false</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>3000</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="18" column="2">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_rozkop">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
         <weight>50</weight>
         <bold>false</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>180</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_21">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>100</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>501</width>
      <height>31</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>24</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>ЗАВДАННЯ</string>
    </property>
    <property name="alignment">
     <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="zavdannia_vidpravka_button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>250</x>
      <y>730</y>
      <width>181</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Відправити дані</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>688</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```