# Как из главного окна получить значения в дочерние окна?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer

Продолжение этой темы: [PyQt5 Как передать значение из дочернего окна в главное](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1067089/pyqt5-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5)

Теперь есть два вопроса:

- Первый: как из окна №3 с таблицы получить значение в окне №2, как только в окне №3 оно будет посчитано?
- Второй: как из окна №1 и окна №2 с `lineedit` взять данные в формате *float* и передать в ячейку таблицы окна №3?

---

**P.S.:**

**main.py** - **`окно №1`**, 
**zavd_form.py** - **`окно №2`**, 
**tabl2_1form.py** - **`окно №3`**.

Comment: Если вам действительно нужна помощь, опубликуйте все модули вашего приложения. И лучше расскажите, что такое окно `№1`, `№2`, `№3`. Что значит - `как только в окне №3 оно будет посчитано` ?

Comment: Так как в проекте несколько файлов, отправляю Вам ссылку на архив со всеми файлами. [ https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vh6ak6GDJAztWVrEHJzhK8f9k6QhcJUo ] main.py - окно №1, zavd_form.py - окно №2, tabl2_1form.py - окно №3

Comment: что-то у меня сбоит ваша ссылка. Сделайте архив `.zip`

Comment: Вот сделал в zip https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bv1UCncxXy-3UNqRVFpZb8X5us5OUbWB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы плохо объяснили, что и куда (конкретно) вы собираетесь вставлять.

Делаю так, как я это понял.

> Как с окна №1 и окна №2 с lineedit взять данные в формате float и передать в ячейку таблицы окна №3?

Реализовано в методе `zavdannia_vidpr` и решил я добавить эти данные в первый столбец таблицы окна №3.
Действие произойдет по нажатию кнопки `Отправить данные.`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Как с окна №3 с таблицы получить значение в окне №2 как только в окне №3 оно будет посчитано?

Реализовано в методе `tabl2_1_rozrahu`. 
Для этого создан словарь куда мы выгрузим все данные из таблицы.
Действие произойдет по нажатию кнопки `Розрахувати таблицю`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic
from zavd_form import zavd_window
from tabl2_1form import tabl2_1_window
#from tabl2_2form import tabl2_2_window


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("main.ui", self)
        self.setWindowTitle('main.py - окно №1')

        self.zavdannia_button.clicked.connect(self.open_zavdannia)
        self.tabl2_1_button.clicked.connect(self.open_tabl2_1)
        #self.tabl2_2_button.clicked.connect(self.open_tabl2_2)

        self.zavdform = zavd_window(self)           # zavd_form.py - окно №2
        self.tabl2_1form = tabl2_1_window(self)     # tabl2_1form.py - окно №3
        #self.tabl2_2form = tabl2_2_window(self)

        self.zavdform.zavdannia_vidpravka_button.clicked.connect(self.zavdannia_vidpr)  # +++
        self.tabl2_1form.tabl2_1_rozrahunokButton.clicked.connect(self.tabl2_1_rozrahu) # +++

        # здесь будем сохранять все значения таблицы из окна №3,
        # где ключ - это номер строки, а 
        # значение - список значений столбцов в этой строке
        self.dict_table = {}                                                            # +++

    def open_zavdannia(self):
        self.zavdform.show()

    def open_tabl2_1(self):
        self.tabl2_1form.show()

    def tabl2_1_rozrahu(self):                                       # +++
        print('Розрахувати таблицю: - окно №3')  
        # Как с окна №3 с таблицы получить значение в окне №2 как только в окне №3 оно будет посчитано? 

        rows = self.tabl2_1form.tableWidget.rowCount()
        columns = self.tabl2_1form.tableWidget.columnCount()
        # print(rows, columns)
        self.dict_table = {}
        for r in range(rows):
            self.dict_table[r] = []
            for c in range(columns):
                self.dict_table[r].append(
                     self.tabl2_1form.tableWidget.item(r, c).text() if self.tabl2_1form.tableWidget.item(r, c) else ''
                 )
            print('{} : {}'.format(r, self.dict_table[r]))

        # использование словаря:
        # предположим, что надо вставить в `zavdform.label_vsogo` 
        # значение ячейки первой строки, первого столбца
        self.zavdform.label_vsogo.setText(self.dict_table[0][0])

    def zavdannia_vidpr(self):                                       # +++
        print('Отправить данные: - окно №2')            

        # Как с окна №1 и окна №2 с lineedit взять данные в формате float 
        # и передать в ячейку таблицы окна №3?
        item = QTableWidgetItem(self.label_kof_2.text())
        self.tabl2_1form.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, item)
        item = QTableWidgetItem(self.label_san_2.text())
        self.tabl2_1form.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, item)
        item = QTableWidgetItem(self.label_vid_2.text())
        self.tabl2_1form.tableWidget.setItem(2, 0, item)     


#    def open_tabl2_2(self):
#        self.tabl2_2form.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**zavd_form.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic


class zavd_window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(zavd_window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        uic.loadUi("zavd.ui", self)
        self.setWindowTitle('zavd_form.py - окно №2')
        self.zavdannia_vidpravka_button.clicked.connect(self.vidpravlennia_znachen)

    def vidpravlennia_znachen(self):
        z_kof = self.zavd_kof.text() if self.zavd_kof.text() else '0'                 # + 
#        self.parent.label_kof_2.setText(str(float(self.zavd_kof.text())))
        self.parent.label_kof_2.setText(z_kof)
        z_san = self.zavd_sanitarni.text() if self.zavd_sanitarni.text() else '0'     # + 
        self.parent.label_san_2.setText(z_san)
        z_vid = self.zavd_vidvedennia.text() if self.zavd_vidvedennia.text() else '0' # + 
        self.parent.label_vid_2.setText(z_vid)    
        z_lis = self.zavd_lisgosp.text() if self.zavd_lisgosp.text() else '0'         # +
        self.parent.label_lisove_gospodarstvo.setText(z_lis) 

    def treluvannia(self):
        pass
    #Тут має бути формула на розрахунок колонки 2.2 трелювання


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = zavd_window()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**tabl2_1form.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic


class tabl2_1_window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(tabl2_1_window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        uic.loadUi("tabl2_1.ui", self)
        self.setWindowTitle('tabl2_1form.py - окно №3')

    def otrimannia_znachen_2_1(self):
        # Тут має бути формула для отримання значень з завдання або бази.
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = tabl2_1_window()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```